# MySQL - Out of memory error

Tags: mysql

Recently I've found "out of memory" errors in the MySQL error log, but the host machine still has enough physical memory and swap space according to `free -k`:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       4087156    3842396     244760          0     615840    2031416
-/+ buffers/cache:    1195140    2892016
```

> [ERROR] Out of memory; check if mysqld or some other process uses all available memory; if not, you may have to use 'ulimit' to allow mysqld to use more memory or you can add more swap space

I've afraid that there is a MySQL bug that is causing a memory leak.

Will the memory usage of MySQL grow dynamically?
If yes, what factor or event will cause MySQL to allocate more memory?
Any possible impact when there is not enough memory for MySQL and how to avoid it?

Here is the machine configuration:
OS Linux 2.6.18-128.el5PAE i386

MySQL Server version: 5.0.50-enterprise-gpl-log MySQL Enterprise Server (GPL)

/etc/my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
port            = 3306
socket          = /tmp/mysql.sock
datadir         = /opt/mysql
skip-locking
key_buffer = 1G
max_allowed_packet = 2M
table_cache = 256
sort_buffer_size = 1M
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache = 32
query_cache_size= 32M
thread_concurrency = 16
max_heap_table_size = 1G

auto_increment_increment = 10
auto_increment_offset = 1

server-id       = 20
log-warnings
log-slow-queries
skip-innodb
skip-slave-start
core-file
```

Comment: Do you check the memory usage at precisely the same time that the out-of-memory errors occur, or after then fact when you see the entry in the logs? Large or inefficient queries can cause the out-of-memory error during execution, but the system will return to normal after the error occurs and the query halts.